# Post api is not working but it works on postman in flutter

Tags: web-services, post, dart, flutter

I am working on one flutter project.On which i am facing one issues on POST api.It works properly in postman but gives error in post method in flutter.
please help me I have used possible solutions.

**Code:**

```
var body = jsonEncode({
        "userid": "2",
        "CUSTOMERID":"158",
        "OFFSET":"0"
});
final response = await http.post(
  "http://18.191.223.160/webservices/FoodSubCategoryList",
   headers: {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Tokenvalue": "sOzz0Y6O",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }, body: body
);
```

**PostMan:-**

[image]

Comment: show postman parameters of body..plz

Comment: {
"CUSTOMERID": "2",
"CATEGORYID": "158",
"OFFSET": "0"
}

Comment: screen shot of postmans... is it json or key value pair of formdata?

Comment: it is json ,Header is :-Tokenvalue:sOzz0Y6O
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     http.Response response = await http.post("http://18.191.223.160/webservices/FoodSubCategoryList",
      body: { "userid": "2",
        "CUSTOMERID":"158",
        "OFFSET":"0"},
       headers: {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Tokenvalue": "sOzz0Y6O",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });
      var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
```

instead of this

```
var body = jsonEncode({
        "userid": "2",
        "CUSTOMERID":"158",
        "OFFSET":"0"
});
final response = await http.post(
  "http://18.191.223.160/webservices/FoodSubCategoryList",
   headers: {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Tokenvalue": "sOzz0Y6O",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }, body: body
);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Crashed : "flutter: Request parameter for subcategory {CUSTOMERID: 2, CATEGORYID: 158, OFFSET: 0}
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json".
"

Comment: i think removing accept and content-type will work for you as these headers are added automatically

Comment: I already check with remove those things ,it gives 412 error code.
While same thing are working on postman ,Strange behaviour.

Comment: just tell me one thing it is get or post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192766/discussion-between-hardik1344-and-primo).

Answer (score 0):

update dependencies http: ^0.12.1