# API endpoint works fine in any Api testing environment like insomnia/ postman but does not work in flutter again

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a flutter app and I have created an API endpoint using Laravel which I have hosted on Heroku. I had consumed the API in the application and all was working well until I restarted my laptop. After the restart, now the API endpoint which was working fine is now returning status code 500 but the same endpoint still works fine in insomnia/postman.

I faced the same issue two days ago and I thought I did something wrong so I created a new endpoint only for me to be facing the same issue today as well.

I am well aware that in my flutter app, I am supposed to use HTTPS://url and that is exactly what I am doing.

I have read this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967076/post-api-is-not-working-but-it-works-on-postman-in-flutter) and this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73415647/api-works-fine-in-postman-but-throws-401-unauthorizedexception-in-flutter-app) but none solves my issue

**What could be the problem?**

**below is my API calling service class which keeps throwing the exception message. This same service class was working perfectly until the laptop restart**

```
class RemoteService {
  RemoteService();
  ProjectApis _projectApis = ProjectApis();
  Client client = http.Client();

  Future<List<Department>> getDepartments() async {
    http.Response response = await client.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
    );

    debugPrint("The response.statusCode is: ${response.statusCode}");

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      debugPrint("The response body is: ${response.body}");
      debugPrint("The response.statusCode y is: ${response.statusCode}");
      return (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((data) => Department.fromJson(data))
          .toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load departments');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is usually caused due to nonavailability of headers during the call. Add all headers you have from Postman to your query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After adding the headers, now the status code has changed to 401 (unauthenticated). So I tried to rebuild the app and then authenticate a user but still, I keep getting 401 now. Have any idea as to why that?

Comment: If it's an unauthenticated error, then your request is being sent to the server. Check that you are sending your auth credentials with your request in dio. What are you using for auth, access token?

Comment: I am using email and password for the auth and I am also using token for data persistence

Answer (score 1):

If your server is returning an error like this then there is a possibility that some exception/error occurred on the server side, could you please print some log at your API endpoint to see what is happening?

> 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: using debugPrint() as shown in the code excerpt sent above print 401. It used to be 501 though but changed after adding headers. Is that what you asked for?

Comment: 401 mainly leads to unauthorized requests, are you using any authentication mechanism like a JWT token? If so then make sure you are passing the correct access token in your headers.